# Dynamic Typescript type for methods passed in

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have

```
interface User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

interface Car {
    year: number;
    model: string;
}

interface Action<T> {
    assign<K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]): void;
}
```

This allows me to do:

```
const userActions: Action<User> = ...;
const carActions: Action<Car> = ...;

userActions.assign('age', 1); // all good
userActions.assign('foo', 2); // error that `foo` does not exist
userActions.assign('age', 'foo'); // error that type string is not assignable to age

carActions.assign(...); // same behavior for car
```

Now I want to create auxiliary methods that can be passed to `assign`, for example:

```
const logAndAssign = (key, value): void;
```

And I want to be able to do

```
userActions.assign(logAndAssign('age', 1));
// etc
```

And so I want these aux methods `logAndAssign` to get the type passed to them. How can I achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK, as you've described it, this won't be possible (even in plain js). Since a function can only return a single value, there's no way for the `logAndAssign` call to fill in both arguments to `.assign`, it would only be able to fill in the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a function with a single argument directly, you could use `apply` but `apply` call would not be type safe and calling `logAndAssign` would imply you passing the type arguments explicitly:

```
const logAndAssign = function <T, K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]): [K, T[K]] {
    console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
    return [key, value];
};
userActions.assign.apply(userActions, logAndAssign<User, 'age'>('age', 1));
```

A better solution would be replace the `assign` function on `Action` and then restore it:

```
function withLogging<T>(a: Action<T>, doStuff: (a: Action<T>) => void) {
    let oldAssign = a.assign;
    // Replace the assign function with a logging version that calls the original
    a.assign = function <K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]): void {
        console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
        oldAssign.call(this, key, value);
    };
    try {
        doStuff(a);
    } finally {
        //Restore the original assign 
        a.assign = oldAssign;
    }
}
// Single call
withLogging(userActions, u => u.assign('age', 10));
// Multiple calls
withLogging(userActions, u => {
    u.assign('age', 10);
    u.assign("name", 'd');
});
```